# Bootable USB Stick not working without `nomodeset`

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

I have a bootable USB drive which holds Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I've installed Ubuntu without a problem using that stick.

Now, I had some problems and I can't boot Ubuntu anymore.

I decided to do a format but now that same USB stick does not start the installer unless I'm adding the `nomodeset` parameter to the installer options.

How is that possible and how can I resolve this issue?

Kind regards

Comment: Since you are likely to just need to use this option once until you finish the install... is this a problem? The USB stick probably has a problem finding the correct settings for your graphics card. That could be a timing issue (ie. the stick is slower to boot back when it did work).  What matters: does the install work and do you get a working desktop when it is done. If there then still is a problem you might opt to recreate the installer ;)

Comment: After installing I can't boot without nomodeset. Will try to create new installer. Any idea?

Comment: What video card/chip. Normally you have to only use nomodeset on first boot or until you install proprietary driver. IF AMD perhaps bigger issue.

Comment: The weird thing is that the stick was working a few days ago to install Ubuntu. I have an Hp envy  700-229eb. Any ideas? It's really driving me nuts...

Comment: Your model has several variants, ones with simple Intel graphics, others with Nvidia (GTX950M). You need nomodeset for the latter, during installation and until you install the recommended Nvidia proprietary drivers. Versions 352, 361, 367 and 370 support your card.